# PHP array_search() not returning the proper index

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find a certain line in a file. The file is http://cpcheats.co/pin-tracker/swf/coffee.flr. I'm using the php function search_array(), but it is not giving me the proper key. This code just returns the first line of the file:

```
$newurl = file_get_contents("http://cpcheats.co/pin-tracker/swf/coffee.flr");
$array = explode("\n",$newurl);
$key = array_search('triggers_mc.pin_mc.triggerFunction = function () {', $array);
echo $array[$key];
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, or a fix for this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$array` actually has more than 1 element?

Comment: The file has 4 spaces before the 'triggers_mc.pin_mc.triggerFunction = function () {' line so the value isn't found in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you are missing the 4 space characters from the beginning of your search term.

```
$key = array_search('    triggers_mc.pin_mc.triggerFunction = function () {', $array);
```

works fine.

A possible solution if you don't want to include the spaces in your search term would be to loop through `$array` and trim the values before calling `array_search`.

Comment: preg_grep() will be faster on a single search

Answer (score 1):

Add four spaces before your search value.

Answer (score 0):

> *`Array_search()` returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.*
>
> *(int)FALSE == 0*

Something is wrong with your `$needle`, array_search returns false, thus `$key = 0`;